# Greedy segment with .NET MVC 5 Attribute Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

I would like to define a route as follows -

```
[Route("clients/{*code}/{id:guid}/update")]
public ActionResult Update(string code, Guid id)
{
}
```

Code will be something like "foo/bar/xyz".

Unfortunately, out-of-the-box MVC doesn't support greedy parameters in the middle of a Route definition.

This has previously been [solved](http://erraticdev.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/custom-aspnet-mvc-route-class-with.html) using the old MVC routing conventions, however I would like to have this as a RouteAtribute defintion.

Comment: would a path of `clients/{id:guid}/update/{*code}` be acceptable?

Comment: @DaveAlperovich sadly not, as that would be at the end of the url. The route needs to support a greedy parameter in the middle.

Comment: I don't think that pattern can be implemented with route attribute

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot do it directly. However, you should be able to use **IIS module UrlRewrite** and rewrite the query with a greedy parameter in the middle to the one with a greedy parameter at the end.

So a client queries:  `clients/{*code}/{id:guid}/update` 
and your web api sees `clients/{id:guid}/update/{*code}`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell there is no out-of-the-box way of doing this other than to use custom code like [this example](http://erraticdev.blogspot.nl/2011/01/custom-aspnet-mvc-route-class-with.html). Hope it helps.